# Kendo-Grid-Column header font size

Tags: html, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

how to change the font size of Kendo-Grid-Column header in html?

By default it's very big and I tried to add font-size:medium; to the column style but still not working.

I tried [headerStyle] as the following [link](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/styling/)

I got this error: Can't bind to 'headerStyle' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-grid'.

Comment: Please post your code. The linked example clearly shows that it should be working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
        <kendo-grid-column
          field="ContactName"
          title="Contact Name"
          [width]="150"
          [headerStyle]="{'font-size' : '3rem'}"
        >
```

Stackblitz:
https://angular-aprxae.stackblitz.io

Be sure to import the GridModule in `app.component`:

```
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, FormsModule, GridModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Comment: I tried to add [headerClass]="{'headerStyle': 'true'}" in column definition, and in css: headerStyle {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 5px;
} but it didn't work.

Comment: your way has worked. but I dnt want to repeat the style for every column

Comment: Use it on the column directive, it should only do it for that one column

Comment: How can we add it for multiple columns without repeating style everytime?

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm <3